# What causes border around custom title bars in Android? (N.B. not asking for a fix)

Tags: android, titlebar

I was making a custom title bar in Android and I found that my title bar didn't fill the entire area of the default title bar. The default color (blue) of the old title bar "leaks" around the edges, creating a blue border around my custom title bar despite the fact that my title bar uses...

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

There have been many threads on this and many of them seem to involve changing the background color of the default container, or setting its padding, and some of these solutions don't seem to work on tablets and some of them seem hackish.

My question is **NOT** how to fix this (like I said, there are many threads on it), so don't mark this as a duplicate! but could someone please explain what **causes** the border around custom title bars?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the border around came from the style , look inside the style file  under res/values/style 
search for  actionbar style

Comment: Action bar is a Honeycomb feature.   I'm running Gingerbread.